# How do I remove multiple files with a common prefix and suffix?

Tags: files

I have many files named

```
sequence_1_0001.jpg  
sequence_1_0002.jpg  
sequence_1_0003.jpg  
...
```

and files named

```
sequence_1_0001.hmf  
sequence_1_0002.hmf  
sequence_1_0003.hmf  
...
```

and files named

```
sequence_2_0001.jpg  
sequence_2_0002.jpg  
sequence_2_0003.jpg  
...
```

and

```
sequence_2_0001.hmf  
sequence_2_0002.hmf  
sequence_2_0003.hmf  
...
```

I just want to remove the files that begin with 'sequence_1' and end in '.hmf', but I don't want to remove them one by one, since there are thousands of files.  How can I specify to the rm command that I want to remove all that begin with the prefilx 'sequence_1' and end in '.hmf'?

I'm currently working with a RedHat Linux system, but I'd like to know how to do it on other distributions as well.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
rm sequence_1*.hmf
```

removes files beginning with `sequence_1` and ending with `.hmf`.

---

Globbing is the process in which your shell takes a pattern and expands it into a list of filenames matching that pattern.  Do not confuse it with regular expressions, which is different. 
If you spend most of your time in `bash`, the Wooledge Wiki has a good [page on globbing (pathname expansion)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).  If you want maximum portability, you'll want to read the [POSIX spec on pattern matching](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13) as well / instead.

---

In the unlikely case you run into an *"Argument list too long"* error, you can take a look at [BashFAQ 95](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/095), which addresses this.  The simplest workaround is to break up the glob pattern into multiple smaller chunks, until the error goes away.  In your case, you could probably get away with splitting the  match by prefix digits 0 through 9, as follows:

```
for c in {0..9}; do rm sequence_1_"$c"*.hmf; done
rm sequence_1*.hmf  # catch-all case
```

Comment: This is a very clever work around the 'argument list too long' error.  In my case, I have twenty thousand files, so I guess I would have to use a for loop from 0,..,20.  Right?

Comment: @Paul Right, just break the list into as many chunks as you need, although at some point the `find` approach becomes easier than guess and check.

Comment: upvoted for the `for` solution. Somehow I could not get to figure out how to use `find -regex` to match my files and your solution works just fine!

Answer (score 14):

Although jw013's answer is correct w.r.t globbing, that command may fail if you have thousands of matches: the expanded command line `rm sequence_1_0001.hmf sequence_1_0002.hmf ...` generated by the shell may simply be too big.

As Dom suggested, you can also use the `-delete` option with `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'sequence_1*.hmf' -delete
```

<sup>Both `-maxdepth` and `-delete`, while not in the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) are fairly common in `find` implementations in the wild.  Linux distributions generally use GNU `find`, which certainly supports those options.</sup>

Comment: If you can, use the -delete option for find, it doesn't fork for each file...

Comment: Added, cheers.  Looks like `-delete` should be supported on recent GNU _and_ BSD systems, while `-print0` is GNU-only. So it's likely more portable too (although it shouldn't make a difference for the OP).

Comment: At least OS X's find has -print0, but it's not included in POSIX.

Answer (score 5):

```
rm sequence_1_{0000..0999}.hmf
rm sequence_1_{1000..1999}.hmf
rm sequence_1_{2000..2999}.hmf
...
```

would work too in Bash.

Comment: The brace expansion requires `bash`, and the zero padded form needs version 4, I believe.